# How to count number of occurences of items in an array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

i would like to count an arraylist in kotlin. What I have is something along the lines of :

```
val names = listOf("apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "banana", "pears", "grape", "apricots")
```

Where the output I want is something to be like this :

apple : 2
orange : 2
banana : 1
pears : 1
grape : 1
apricots : 1

can you helped me, thanks

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-occurrences-elements-list-java/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a HashMap to count the occurrences of each word in the ArrayList.

```
val names = listOf("apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "banana", "pears", "grape", "apricots")
val frequencyMap: MutableMap<String, Int> = HashMap()

for (s in names) {
    var count = frequencyMap[s]
    if (count == null) count = 0
    frequencyMap[s] = count + 1
}

println(frequencyMap)
```

Answer (score 9):

using [eachCount](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count.html#) and [groupingBy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#groupingby) might also be a good solution for this.

for example:

```
val names = listOf("apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "banana", "pears", "grape", "apricots")
val frequencies = names.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
print(frequencies)

//{apple=2, orange=2, banana=1, pears=1, grape=1, apricots=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
val names = listOf("apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "banana", "pears", "grape", "apricots")

val output = names.groupBy { it }
    .map { "${it.key} : ${it.value.size}" }
    .toString()

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupingBy and eachcount,

if u want to check u can use groupby after that u can print

```
val count = names.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
println(count)
```